# Visual Studio 2010 err# U1095, NMAKE

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, include, nmake

I'm writing a program in C using Visual Studio 2010, and I am getting the following error:

> U1095: expanded command line '(here come includes-includes-includes)'.

Some of my colleagues get the same error while others do not. The only easy feasible solution I've tried is to update NMAKE itself from a shady website (NMAKE is very hard to find).

Erasing `include` entries helps, but eventually we hit the limit again. One hack that works is to use all the includes in a single file per Microsoft's offering and read from that file but I'd prefer to not have to do that.

Is there an official way to update `nmake` without installing the Windows SDK or Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: @Ness It's just a hundreds of file paths after *<AdditionalIncludeDirectories>*. Important was a concept, not the code. And sorry for the boxes, first time I really couldn't find the answer and had to ask myself.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend using anything in programming in general that you "downloaded from a shady source". That sounds like a good way to embed viruses in your shipped code unknowingly. There is no nmake standalone, so you will be forced to use the one that ships with Visual Studio.

Some things you could try:

1. Attempt using [32-bit and 64-bit](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/585739/where-to-find-nmake-exe-for-64-bit-used-on-visual-studio-2008-professional-edition) versions of nmake and see if you get different results.
2. Get a more recent version of Visual Studio and see if it works better there.

Comment: turned out to be really hard to get a standalone *nmake*, had to download the full MS-VS-2015. Neither helped, though.

Comment: @ClarkYeah - It's been a similar story trying to compile native for node.js until this came along [windows-build-tools](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools), might try installing it and seeing if it by chance helps your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for your responses, guys.
Manipulations with *nmake* didn't help at all.
**The answer is**: to completely erase a sandbox and get a clean one. So it wasn't MS-VS-2010 problem standalone, but a combination of problems between MS-VS and MKS/PTC Integrity.